# How to open a html page as popup within another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript. Now I have a link in home page which redirects to other html page, but I want to show that as a popup in my home page with responsiveness and some styles like a corner is folded.Is there any way to do that in javascript.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thanks for the comment @VXp..I don't want it to open in other window.On same windpw it should load and also it should responsive

Comment: Np, you have multiple examples, the first one opens as separate page but then you can set its width and height etc., you've said you want a popup, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: yes @VXp..but it is not responsive.

Comment: You need to make it responsive, that site that opens, of course it's not responsive by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `<iframe>` to display the another page content in the modal content.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
iframe {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="www.google.com">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @suzan . this is similar to what I am looking for.how to do it without button and when page loads?

Comment: it still has launch demo modal button. How to show popup when page loads without clicking on any button. I noticed you added window load function, but if click on run code snippet it shows launch demo modal button only

Comment: I don't want to put the button in my html @suzan

Comment: @Ash It does not work in the snippet as it is using `$(window).load()`. Please try it in your machine. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "modal box", and here is how to do it: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

As for styling, you can simply use CSS. For example to [round corner](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp) in the linked example, just add e.g. `border-radius: 25px;` to `.modal-content`, so that you have

```
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

For folded corners in specific, there are also plenty of examples, e.g. https://codepen.io/brownerd/pen/lEHwL or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457088/9593181